# Duda sobre complejidad bfs

Tags: algoritmos

En algunos textos(muchos), donde se explica el algoritmo [BFS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_en_anchura) (Búsqueda en anchura - *Breadth First Search*) se encuentra un apartado que dice que la complejidad de ésta es `O(v+e)`, o en su defecto `O(v2)`. Es decir un problema P, pero en algunos textos de IA, cuando explican este algoritmo, salen que la complejidad es `O(XV)`. O sea, exponencial, lo cual lo convierte en un problema NP la cual tiene mucho mayor sentido la explicación que dan.

Mi duda es de dónde sale la complejidad de `O(v+e)` u `O(v2)`.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta es, valen las dos. Porque todo depende de cómo estés analizando las cosas.

Las preguntas que deberías hacerte son, ¿qué estoy recorriendo? ¿Qué tan grande es el árbol que forma el algoritmo? ¿Sé que tan grande es? ¿Para el algoritmo en algún momento?

Para recorrer todo el grafo debo atravesar todos los nodos pasando por todos los ejes (en el peor caso tenemos `n2` ejes, con `n` la cantidad de nodos).

Ahora bien, BFS forma un árbol, asumiendo que la cantidad de ejes por nodos es `x` y `x` es máximo, para ir de un nivel a otro del árbol recorro `x-1`  ejes por cada nodo del nivel.

Pues si estoy el nodo `v` y llegué a él mediante el eje `(u,v)` no voy a recorrer nuevamente ese eje (lo voy a ignorar). Es decir, que al llegar a las hojas del árbol se habrán recorrido `xn` ejes, donde `n` es la distancia de las hojas a la raíz.

Veamos que esto se cumple en un grafo finito y completo (el de `n2` ejes).

De la raíz al siguiente nivel el algoritmo recorrerá `n` ejes.

Luego en el siguiente nivel, que tiene `n` nodos, el recorrerá `n-1` ejes por nodo del nivel, es decir recorrerá `(n-1)*n` ejes.

Es decir, en total `n+(n-1)*n`. Lo cuál da `n2`.

Comment: @Mariano, ¿dónde está la referencia a como escribir en notación matemática? (Se agregadece no tener que bucear en la ayuda)

Comment: Me refiero a dejarlo más legibles, por ejemplo ahora si edito encuentro cosas como <code>n<sup>2</sup></code>

Comment: Al editar, yendo a ayuda http://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help está el enlace al HTML permitido: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/304899

Comment: Acá encontré [info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow?noredirect=1#comment386203_60020) como alternativa si es complejo lo que hay que escribir.

Comment: Me refiero a insertar una imagen generada en [codecogs LaTex](https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)